# Install specific insider preview build for Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview

I wonder whether there is a way to access and install old preview builds for **Windows Mobile 10** or to revert back to a specific version.

To be more specific, the goal is to get a preview build running which still has the *Astoria* component included.

I'm an insider and already had e.g. build 14267 installed (which should still contain the *Astoria* component - not 100% sure though). Project *Astoria* was officially abandoned at the end of February this year. It would still be interesting for me to try it out as I missed the chance earlier this year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I managed to get an Astoria build installed on my Lumia 930 a few days ago. There are ROMs for the 930 and 640(XL) on [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/general/installed-leaked-windows-10-mobile-t3173000) including a how-to on how to install it - worked for me.

FYI If you're trying to run Pokemon Go - won't work.. Just got a black screen with nothing happening :-(

Comment: haha, you got me there. That was indeed one app I liked to try. But there are a few more - hopefully working ones - I will definitely aim to get those running.
So, there does not seem to be an official rollback / installer for older versions as it seems, correct?

Comment: :D
no, as far as I can tell installing this inofficial ROM is the only way to do it